# How to properly iterate/print a parquet using scala/spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

How do I println the individual elements of a parquet containing nested array of objects in spark/scala?

```
{"id" : "1201", "name" : "satish", "age" : "25", "path":[{"x":1,"y":1},{"x":2,"y":2}]}
{"id" : "1202", "name" : "krishna", "age" : "28", "path":[{"x":1.23,"y":2.12},{"x":1.23,"y":2.12}]}
```

Specifically I want to be able to iterate over the object and print out the id, name, and age... then each item in the path. Then move on to printing the next record and soforth. Assuming I have read in the parquet file and have the dataframe, I want to do something like the following (pseudocode):

```
val records = dataframe.map {
  row => {
    val id = row.getString("id")
    val name = row.getString("id")
    val age = row.getString("age")
    println("${id} ${name} ${age}")
    row.getArray("path").map {
         item => {
              val x = item.getValue("x")
              val y = item.getValue("y")
              println("${x} ${y}")
         }
    }
  }
}
```

Not sure if the above is the right way to go about it, but it should give you an idea of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("ParquetAppendMode")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._


  val data1 = spark.read.json("/home/sakoirala/IdeaProjects/SparkSolutions/src/main/resources/explode.json")

  val result = data1.withColumn("path", explode($"path"))

  result.withColumn("x", result("path.x"))
  .withColumn("y", result("path.y")).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----+-------+-----------+----+----+
|age|  id|   name|       path|   x|   y|
+---+----+-------+-----------+----+----+
| 25|1201| satish|  [1.0,1.0]| 1.0| 1.0|
| 25|1201| satish|  [2.0,2.0]| 2.0| 2.0|
| 28|1202|krishna|[1.23,2.12]|1.23|2.12|
| 28|1202|krishna|[1.23,2.12]|1.23|2.12|
+---+----+-------+-----------+----+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this entirely using the Dataframe API; no need to use `map`.

Here is how you can easily flatten your schema by projecting the fields you want to use:

```
val records = dataframe.select("id", "age", "path.x", "path.y")
```

You can then print your data using show:

```
records.show()
```